# spin.js não é exibido quando a página é carregada

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando [Spin.js](https://spin.js.org/) para exibir um load até que página toda seja carregada, feito isso, a execução do spin deve ser encerrada. Mas o load nem está aparecendo na tela. Criei um [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzhx106b/2/) como exemplo:

```
 <script>
    $(document).on(showLoading);
  </script> 
  <body>
       Content
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on(removeLoading);
    });
</script>
```

**Script.js**

```
var mySpinner = null;

function setupLoading() {
    $('<div id="divSpin" />').appendTo(document.body);

    var target = document.getElementById("divSpin");

    var opts = {
        lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
        length: 20, // The length of each line
        width: 10, // The line thickness
        radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
        rotate: 8, // The rotation offset
        direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
        color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
        trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
        shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        className: 'mySpin', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
        top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
        left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
    };

    mySpinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
}

function removeLoading() {
    mySpinner.stop();
}

    function showLoading() {
        mySpinner.spin();
    }
```

Comment: Falta vc carregar as bibliotecas .js e .css.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá:

#### Bug #1: Chamar o script

o código javascript que cria o spinner não existe na página. é necessário referenciá-lo no HTML, senão as funções `showLoading` e `removeLoading` não existirão.

para isso é preciso chamar seu script (deduzo que esteja salvo no mesmo diretório do index.html, com um nome tipo "meuSpin.js"):

```
    <script src="meuSpin.js"></script>
```

> No caso do JSFIDDLE, o javascript é inserido automaticamente no resultado.

**Mas**, neste caso, seu script serve para mostrar um loading **ENQUANTO** a pagina está carregando, portanto a primeira coisa que deve aparecer na página é seu script de loading. Chamar uma referência a um script externo implica em uma requisição extra, e alguns navegadores podem decidir chamá-lo **após** o conteúdo ser exibido, portanto seu script poderia não servir para nada.

Neste caso, o mais sábio seria deixar o código **junto** com a chamada do `showLoading`.

---

#### Bug #2: Scripts que manipulam o DOM fora do HTML

No seu script, na função `setupLoading` (que, veja bug #3, não é chamada), você manipula o DOM, criando um elemento para conter o spinner:

```
$('<div id="divSpin" />').appendTo(document.body);
```

**document.body** ainda nem existe.

a solução neste caso é deixar o script **logo após abrir a tag** :

```
    <body>
      <script>
        $(document).on(showLoading);
      </script>
      ...
      ...
      </script>
        // esconde o loading
      </script>
    </body>
```

> O JsFiddle automaticamente insere o conteudo da aba HTML dentro do **body** do resultado, portanto a tag `<head>` é ignorada.
>
> Como contrapartida, eles disponibilizam opcões dentro da area de Javascript sobre como seu código será inserido.
>
> Clique em "Javascript ▼", e em **LOAD TYPE**, selecione **No Wrap - Bottom of HEAD**
>
> Isso significa que irão colocar seu script no final de `<head>`. Portanto ainda precisaremos do jQuery `on("ready"`

---

#### Bug 3: Uso da livraria Spin.js

A função `showLoading` chama o spin do mySpinner. Portanto ela espera que **mySpinner** seja uma instancia de `new Spinner(opts)`.

Para isto precisamos chamar a porção de código `mySpinner = new Spinner(opts)` antes de chamar `mySpinner.spin(target)`.

isso tudo acontece apenas dentro de `setupLoading()`.

---

#### Bug #4: Dependências

Spin.js não tem nenhuma dependencia, portanto deve funcionar naturalmente. Seu código por outro lado depende de jQuery.

Para isto você precisa inserir o jQuery antes de chamar `$()`

Deduzo que no seu código já exista uma tag chamando o Spin.js:

```
    <head>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="spin.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

> No caso do JSFIDDLE, é necessário configurar seu fiddle com as dependencias:
>
> Clique em "Javascript ▼", em **Frameworks and Extensions**, abra o dropdown e selecione jQuery (edge)
>
> Para adicionar o Spin.js, clique em **Resources** logo abaixo do logo azul do JsFiddle, escreva "spin.js" na caixa de texto, e selecione **spin.js** da lista de autocomplete. Em seguida clique no + no círculo para adicioná-lo ao seu fiddle.

---

#### Bug #5: Uso do jQuery

Se a intenção do loading é mostrar enquanto o conteúdo não carrega, saiba que ele não vai aparecer até, ao menos, o Spin.js e o jQuery.js tenham sido carregados.

Se ainda quiser usar o jQuery, apenas precisa ajustar o jeito que chama as funções.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      ...
    })
```

- $() chama o seletor do jQuery, envolvendo o elemento como um objeto jquery.
- [document](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) é uma variavel global do js, representa o documento da página.
- .ready(fn) é um método do jquery que chama uma função **fn** quando o objeto jquery do qual foi chamado (no caso $(document)) estiver pronto, carregado.

Portanto apenas será chamada quando todo o documento, a tag `<html>`, estiver completamente carregada e pronta para ser manipulada.

> Devido a isto, é necessário inserir uma tag  dentro da area HTML do JsFiddle para conseguir chamar as funções.

Em outro lugar, existe a chamada `$(document).on(removeLoading)`.

`jQuery().on(event, callback)` chama o **callback** quando **event** acontecer. (ou seja, `jQuery.ready(fn)` é um atalho para `jQuery.on("ready",fn)`)

Se você desejava chamar a função **showLoading** ou **hideLoading** quando a página estiver pronta, o código deve ser:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      showLoading()
    })
```

## Final:

Considerando todos os fixes, seu código final deve ficar assim:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Minha Pagina com Spinner</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="spin.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="spin.min.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="divSpin"></div>
        <script>
          var target = document.getElementById("divSpin");

          var opts = {
            lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 20, // The length of each line
            width: 10, // The line thickness
            radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
            corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
            rotate: 8, // The rotation offset
            direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            className: 'mySpin', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
            zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
            top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
            left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
          };

          var mySpinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        </script>

        ...

        <script>
          mySpinner.stop()
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

> Observe que neste código não utilizo `jQuery.ready()`

Bom,

Parece lindo

Mas não vai funcionar.

Mesmo que insira milhares de dados entre os dois scripts, e faça um site com **tanta coisa** que demore pra carregar o suficiente pra conseguir ver o loading, ainda vai ficar frustrado, porque o loading não vai aparecer.

O navegador precisa do **inicio** e do **fim** do html para conseguir exibi-lo. Ou seja, só vai aparecer alguma coisa na sua tela depois que o último  ser enviado. Os scripts também só serão executados depois disso.

Se você precisa mostrar um loading, enquanto o conteúdo é carregado, precisa obter este conteúdo por uma requisição Ajax.

Isso implica em ter no mínimo um servidor HTTP local rodando, para conseguir fazer a requisição na sua própria máquina.

Minha sugestão é buscar como fazer isso com [React](https://reactjs.org/) ou outra ferramenta, que cria um servidor local, facilita a criação de templates e chamadas de código, e não precisa de jQuery mais.

Mas, se não é urgente, é melhor tentar entender o fluxo do DOM, como e quando as funções são chamadas, como o HTML é renderizado, procurar como funcionam os servidores e passar pelo aprendizado de instalar um Nginx ou Apache na sua máquina, entender chamadas AJAX, a API Fetch, e ver como é possível inserir HTML assíncronamente na sua página, para só assim conseguir ver o loading.